# code shows the last line only

Tags: c

```
char ch [1000] ;

while ( fgets(ch,1000,f) !=NULL);
{
   printf("%s",ch) ;
}
```

The file f contains multiple lines but this part of the program only shows the last line

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon here:

```
while ( fgets(ch,1000,f) !=NULL) ;//This one
```

The semicolon makes the loop equivalent to

```
while ( fgets(ch,1000,f) !=NULL)
{}
```

and therefore, has an empty body. The loop goes on executing the `fgets` until it returns `NULL` and when it breaks, `ch` will contain the last line and this is what your `printf` prints.

Comment: Incidentally, `ch` will contain garbage if the file is empty.

Comment: Yeah, since `ch` is a local array.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra `;` at the end of the `while` condition.

Use this style to avoid such mistakes:

```
while (fgets(ch, 1000, f) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", ch);
}
```

Comment: sorry my bad , i copy paste it ( it was do {}while(); )

Comment: @starter: try and avoid `do{}while();` loops as well, they tend to be error prone for beginners.  This is opinion based advice...